# Attempting to instantiate in loop, get unexpected type (expected variable)

Tags: java, loops, instantiation, code-reuse

I'm trying to instantiate three objects in a loop so that I don't reuse the constructor text. This is because, for Uni, we get marked down if we reuse the same line of code (it's marked automatically).

My code is as follows:

```
EnemyShip enemy1;
EnemyShip enemy2;
EnemyShip enemy3;

public Game()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        getEnemyRef(i) = new EnemyShip(); //getEnemyRef unexpected type - required:variable found:value
        //enemy1 = new EnemyShip(); works normally
    }
}
```

The i is underlined and I am told that it is a value not variable.

Please note that I use the following code instead of a list or array because we are not allowed to use them for this task.

```
public EnemyShip getEnemyRef(int enemy) {
    switch (enemy) 
    {
        case 1:
        return enemy1;

        case 2:
        return enemy2;

        case 3:
        return enemy3;
    }
    return null;
}
```

***The marking system bases how many times a line is reused from how many times it is written in source code, not how many times it is executed***

Comment: you need the exact variable name when assigning values. do `EnemyShip e1 = getEnemyRef(i);` before and then `e1 = new enemyShip()`

Comment: you probably wanted something like this: `EnemyShip enemy = getEnemyRef(i);`

Comment: `getEnemyRef(i)` is a method, thus returns a value. You cannot assing something to a value (thus the compiler message: `required:variable found:value`). You constructor call is not the problem, the assignment (or more precise: the left hand side of the assignment) is the problem.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn about arrays and / or Lists.

Comment: What are `enemy1`, `enemy2`, `enemy3`? Where do they come from?

Comment: I have them declared at the top of the code, forgot to include them but just edited it now @Mikhail

Comment: I love when classes teach you bad coding practice in order to get you to do something a certain way using a certain method when in reality you would never do it that way

Comment: @HarryAllen I have updated my answer once again. You may want to have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should do the trick:

```
public void setEnemyRef(int enemyFlag, EnemyShip enemy){
    switch (enemyFlag){
        case 1:
            enemy1 = enemy;
            break;
        case 2:
            enemy2 = enemy;
            break;
        case 3:
            enemy3 = enemy;
            break;
    }
}
```

And then in the `for-loop`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    setEnemyRef(i, new EnemyShip());
}
```

Comment: This does work and meet my requirements but sadly I still lose the marks because it uses the createNew() method three times.

(I lose marks for reuse (more than one usage) of equality checks, sub/add, constructor use, method calls and communication between classes)

Comment: props for creativity, but you are using an array which OP said was not allowed

Comment: @TravisHerbert I've updated, still not sure if that's allowed

Answer (score -1):

You're not instantiating it correctly, try e.g.

`EnemyShip variableName = getEnemryRef(i);
variableName = new EnemyShip();`

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: this code is equivalent to `EnemyShip variableName = new EnemyShip();` (under the assumption that `getEnemyRef(i)` is a method that never throws) and I do not think that this is what OP asks for. Please remember that [Java passes by value always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value), and it returns by value in the same manner.

Comment: Fair enough but his solution to tackle the problem does not seem optimal.

Comment: @JulianAlwandy The predicament that I'm in is that I need to reduce the use of the  constructor '= new EnemyShip();' so that I'm not using three times to create three obejcts. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @HarryAllen No. If you want three distinct objects, you need at least three constructor calls.

Comment: @Turing85 So the only possible way is to use an array/list?

Comment: @HarryAllen I am not sure I follow your train of thoughts. Even in an array/`List<...>`, if you want to store three distring objects in them, you need to first instantiate those three objects (via three constructor calls).

Comment: @Turing85 Maybe I am using the wrong terminology. A loop such as:
while (true) { EnemyShip e = new EnemyShip()    list.add(e) }
Could create more than one object while only using the line once?

Comment: @HarryAllen Well... you WRITE the line only once, but the line (in your example) is executed as often as your heap memory allows it.

Comment: @Turing85 the marking system we are submitting to only counts a use as when it is written, not how many times it is used/executed. It's a bit daft

Comment: @HarryAllen you may want to edit your question and add this information. It is quite crucial to answer it correctly.